# What are Insertions & Deletions in Git?

Tags: git

When I run git commands like `git commit` or `git log --shortstat` part of the output looks like:

```
2 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 11 deletions(-)
```

What is the meaning of an **insertion** or a **deletion**?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It is just number of lines inserted and number of lines deleted in that particular commit. Note that a modified line maybe treated as an insert and a delete.

[Git log manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> --shortstat
>
> Output only the last line of the --stat format containing **total
> number of modified files, as well as number of added and deleted
> lines.**

Comment: So accumulating `insertions - deletions` for `git log --shortstat` == total LOC.  Also, it appears that binary files have no effect on insertions & deletions.

Comment: @manojlds Then how to get the no of lines modified in a commit other than additions, does all deleted lines can be taken as modified?